# Проблема в драйвере или неправильном подключении Arduino Pro Mini?

Tags: arduino

Есть китайская плата, в этой [статье](http://radiolis.pp.ua/arduino/22-znakomstvo-s-arduino-pro-mini-na-primere-kitajskogo-analoga) описано про плату и как ее подключать. Парюсь уже несколько дней, прошить не получается. В диспетчере устройств в COM-порте появляется сама платка, по гуидам пытаюсь поставить драйвера, но про Про Мини особо ничего не нашел. В общем, в папке с Arduino IDE есть папка drivers. В диспетчере жму `Обновить драйвер`, выбираю `arduino.inf`, а дальше что выбрать не знаю. Целевую плату я не вижу. Драйвера ставятся любые :D Пробовал от Uno поставить, но ничего не прошивается, естественно. Хотя монитор порта работает. Список доступных драйверов на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сама же ошибка при прошивке стандартная:

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
```

Плату выбираю `Arduino Pro or Pro Mini`, процессор `ATmega328P (5V, 16MHz)`, кнопочку reset при загрузке нажимаю. Плата сто процентов рабочая, подключено все как на схеме в статье. Мне дали переделать программу, тонкости подключения у того человека узнать нет возможности. Помогите, в чем может быть проблема или моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

После танцев с бубном было выявлено, что ардуинка с проблемами цепляется на Win 10. В видео на youtube нашел в описании драйвер, установка которого помогла. Вначале нужно в диспетчере удалить устройство, если был установлен драйвер другой, потом включить инсталлер с драйвером, после диалогового окна подключить ардуино и нажать "continue". Ссылка на драйвер на [Яндекс.Диск](https://yadi.sk/d/oBQ--99x3AdxnN). [Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RXAdUV35_JM) про прошивку Arduino Pro Mini